# Java streams: how to implement this mapping?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I would like to submit the following mapping case:

```
public class A
{
   private String v1;
   private String v2;
   private String v3;
   ....
}

public class B
{
  private String v2;
  private String v3;
  ...
  public B (A a)
  {
    v2 = a.getV2();
    v3 = a.getV3();
  }
  ...
```

Now, given this two classes, I need to provide the following mapping:

```
List<A> -> Map<String, List<B>>
```

where the String in the map is the value v1 of A obtained by using the groupingBy collector.

I tried several ways to implement this mapping but I can't figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: When you “tried several ways”, show what you have tried and explain why you aren’t happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

First use groupingBy collector on v1 value, then use `mapping` down stream collector to map A instances to corresponding B before collecting it into a mutable container. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, List<B>> v1ToBList = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getV1, 
    Collectors.mapping(B::new, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Your solution works and is better compared with what I could figure out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use return v1 and other strings separately using map function and then collect it by using `Collectors.toMap` function.

```
aList.stream()
        .map(item -> Arrays.asList(item.getV1(), Arrays.asList(item.getV2(), item.getV3())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(list -> list.get(0), list -> l.get(1)));
```

This statement will return a map with required output.

Note that [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) function takes two [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) [Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) each for a key and a value. I can elaborate more on the function if you want.

Lemme know if you want more explanation on how that thing works.